# saving image from web in simulator photo gallery

Tags: iphone

i am downloading an image from the internet but saving it on the desktop.I want to save it in photo gallery of the iphone. How is this possible?

my code is here:

```
NSString *docDir = @"/Users/gaurav/Desktop";
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/neetu%d.png",docDir , r];
r++;

//NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/flower.png",docDir];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
[data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

You only need completionTarget, completionSelector and contextInfo if you want to be notified when the image is done saving, otherwise you can pass in nil.

Answer (score 0):

Look into UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

[UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum working... sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017681/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-working-sometimes)