# Saving Multiple Images to Photo Album Efficiently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, uiimage

When saving multiple images (720x1280 each size) this obvious method below does its job well. However, my app saves up to 10 images in a row and, strangely enough, while I do see log prints all 10 images, in the Photo Album I can see only 5 or so.

Is this a single-threading issue?

```
-(void)saveAllItems:(NSTimer*)sender{
    for(int i=0;i<[imagePaths count];i++){
      NSString *path = (NSString*)[imagePaths objectAtIndex:i];
      UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
      NSLog(@"saveAllItems: saving %d %@",i,path);
      UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img , nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill bet your paths are wrong then.

Comment: Near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017681/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-working-sometimes which has a good answer.

Comment: this method is asynchronous so its possible the save is still happening in background. Do all the images eventually appear? supply callbacks to see if it was a success/failure