# iOS attempting to save image to camera roll but not succeeding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I have an image in an UIImageView and want to save it to the device's photos so that it can be ultimately saved as a wallpaper.  Although the code compiles without an error the image does not save and I fear that I am doing something wrong when it comes to using 'UIImage' vs 'UIImageView' or something else all together.  The name of the image is "Q115birdsfull~iphone.png" and my code thus far is below. What am I doing wrong???

**Q115birdsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Q115birdsViewController : UIViewController 
{
    UIImage *Q115birdsfull;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *Q115birdsfull;

- (IBAction)onClickSavePhoto:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Q115birdsViewController.m**

```
#import "Q115birdsViewController.h"

@interface Q115birdsViewController ()
@end

@implementation Q115birdsViewController

@synthesize Q115birdsfull;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (IBAction)onClickSavePhoto:(id)sender{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(Q115birdsfull, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

`
Thank you in advance!

Comment: first off, this has nothing to do with Xcode but instead with iOS, so I'm removing all mention of Xcode for you.  :-)

Comment: I see what you mean Michael. Thx!

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017681/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-working-sometimes

Comment: Hey again. Does `Q115birdsfull` actually contain an image? I don't see you giving it any data at all.

Comment: @qegal Thanks again so much! Perhaps I have missed a step. I am using storyboard and draged an Image View onto a View Controller and then assigned my .png image from my Supporting Files + the code above of course.

Comment: @ewiinnnn Thx! I hadn't noticed this link in my search but it didn't quite help me. I fear that I am making a simple error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS save image to camera roll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131050/ios-save-image-to-camera-roll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're attempting to save is a `UIImage` kept as a property and an ivar.  What I *don't* see in your code is where you actually set that image to anything.  That may be the step you are missing.

Try doing this:

```
- (IBAction)onClickSavePhoto:(id)sender{

    if(Q115birdsfull == NULL)
    {
        NSLog( @"there is no Q115birdsfull image set");
        Q115birdsfull = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Q115birdsfull"];

        // if it's STILL null, we'll try a much more specific name
        if(Q115birdsfull == NULL)
        {
            Q115birdsfull = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Q115birdsfull~iphone"];
        }
    }

    if(Q115birdsfull){
        // by the way, variable names should *always* start with lower case letters
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(Q115birdsfull, nil, nil, nil);
    }
    else {
        NSLog( @"never found the Q115birdsfull png file... is it really being copied into your built app?");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are amazing! It totally worked. I was flagged to at an "@" in front of the image name which I will add to your code above. Thanks you sooooooooooo much!

Comment: by the way, I hope you didn't miss my comment about Objective C naming styles:  variables and method names should *always* start with lower case letters and class names should start with capital letters.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I did notice that...thank you as well...I will make this change. Much appreciated. So I couldn't edit the code above because the change needed to be 6 characters or more so I will try to post below. Thank you again so much!!!

Comment: So I can't post the answer with the edit for another 7 hours it seems. I will tomorrow then.